# Custom pageoutlets are not editable in SmartEdit

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have created a custom outlet and placed it in `app.component.html`

```
<app-outlet></app-outlet>
<cx-storefront>Loading...</cx-storefront>
```

The template `app-outlet.component.html` contains

```
<ng-template cxOutletRef="CustomOutletSlot" cxOutletPos="replace">
  // this replace outlet works in storefront
</ng-template>
```

In storefront, the pages are loading as expected. 
Sure, it also shows in SmartEdit, but the contextual menus `Drag & Drop`, `Edit`, and `Remove` are not showing?

Are there any workaround for this? I still need to use the custom outlet in my case.

Answer (score 0):

SmartEdit is about managing CMS Components and Content Slots.  It works against backend data structures supported by SAP Commerce: pages have content slots, and content slots contain components.  When you modify via SmartEdit, you are updating the content slots, the components, and the relationships between them.

When you are using a custom outlet ... that is not a data item understood by the backend CMS functionality.  There is no data element in the backend for SmartEdit to manipulate.

If you want to have this item manageable via SmartEdit - you will need to create and use CMS Content Slots / Components